# Using obfs4; Tor fails to connect

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

```
5/30/2015 10:37:51 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/30/2015 10:37:51 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/30/2015 10:37:57 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
5/30/2015 10:37:57 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
5/30/2015 10:38:18 AM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to x.x.x.x:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/30/2015 10:38:57 AM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to x.x.x.x:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/30/2015 10:38:57 AM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to x.x.x.x:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/30/2015 10:44:05 AM.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/30/2015 10:44:05 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/30/2015 10:44:05 AM.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

I'm using OBFS4 since it's the only pluggable transport that can pass my ISP restriction, other bridges fail..

Comment: Which pluggable transport are you using? If you are using the new obfsproxy (obfsproxy in Tor Browser 4.0 or later), it might be an internal error or it could not make a connection to the bridge. Try using another bridge.

Comment: Please provide which version of the Tor Browser you're using ('the latest version' is not a good answer), whether you verified the authenticity of the downloaded software, and which OS you're using. Depending on the situation, downloading a fresh Tor Browser might help. Since you might have just accidentally messed with something. (e.g I'm wondering why `DisableNetwork` is set, the default value is 0 -- this might be an indicator that your Tor Browser is misconfigured) Also you might wanna try an `obfs4` bridge on port `443` or `80`.

Comment: DisableNetwork will be set as soon as you click 'configure' to prevent leaks .